# Save As Dialog box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, savefiledialog

I have web application(asp.net).is there any way to show a 'SAVE AS DIALOG BOX'(in browser) when user clicks the download button.i have tried several codes but i didn't get expected result.all are download the file normally to downloads(default download path of browser).is it possible to open save as dialog box in web browser

Comment: That is completely impossible.

Comment: The browser user interface belongs to the  user, not to the web developer. What if the user has told the browser _not_ to display a Save As dialog?

Comment: The concept isn't impossible - obviously you can't open the system's file dialogue, there may be a way to tell the browser that a file is ready for downloading.  This would bring up the browser's file dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered: 
[[Save dialog box to download file, Saving file from ASP.NET server to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833490/asp-net-c-save-dialog-box-to-download-file-saving-file-from-asp-net-server-to][1])

Comment: hi nader ,i have tried this code.i got an exception on response.Flush();   "[System.Threading.ThreadAbortException] = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}"   and the file is downloaded normally without open save as dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for download a file in asp.net?
Please see sample below.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/MyFile.pdf"));
Response.End();
```

> ```
> .htm, .html     Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
> .txt    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
> .doc, .rtf, .docx    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
> .xls, .xlsx    Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
> .jpg, .jpeg    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
> .gif    Response.ContentType =  "image/GIF";
> .pdf    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
> ```

[How to download a file in ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: Not sure if the post would be even valid comment in current state. Please provide summary of the link inline if you believe article shows answer to the question.

Comment: I will provide the details.. I will edit my post later. Have to take a quick lunch first ;)... Thanks for reminding me :)